# Is it possible to use regex matching different part of one word in python?

Tags: python

I did a little research and it seems to be called non-consuming regex, but it is not working with `re.sub()`. What I want to archive is to delete a part of a non-space-separating string. The pattern of original string is `pubmed23n[0-9]*\.xml\.gz`, and I want to keep only the `[0-9]*` part of the string.
Example:

Before:

```
pubmed23n0001.xml.gz
```

After:

```
0001
```

Now I need to walk two steps to archive that, namely substitute `^pubmed23n` and `\.xml\.gz` or substitute `(^pubmed23n)|(\.xml\.gz)` twice. I tried to use `(?=pubmed23n)(?=\.xml\.gz)` or `(?<=pubmed23n)(?<=\.xml\.gz)` but with no luck.

The strings are siting within a list and I want to delete some of the string based on a number. The current approach I'm trying to do is:

```py
def remove_item(keep_from: int):
    ptn1 = r'^pubmed23n'
    ptn2 = r'\.xml\.gz$'
    # some func to get and sort the list of file names with pattern `pubmed23n[0-9]*\.xml\.gz` and assign to `filename_list`
    # example of filename_list: ['pubmed23n0001.xml.gz','pubmed23n0002.xml.gz','pubmed23n0003.xml.gz']
    filename_cut_list = [re.sub(ptn1,'',i) for i in filename_list]
    filename_cut_list = [re.sub(ptn2,'',i) for i in filename_cut_list]
    filename_cut_list = [int(i) for i in filename_cut_list]
    if filename_cut_list.index(keep_from) != 0:
        del filename_list[:filename_cut_list.index(keep_from)+1]
```

Because the list to be handled could have thousands of element I want to make it to run once. But if I don't even need to go though this much to delete the items with number smaller than given in the string, I also more than glad to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing fixed strings, you don't need a regular expression. Just use `str.replace()`.

```
filename_cut_list = [int(i.replace('pubmed23n', '').replace('.xml.gz', '')) for i in filename_list]
```

Comment: I kept thinking regex and forgot totally this simple solution!

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: Just a small note, the second replace missed a argument, updated: `filename_cut_list = [int(i.replace('pubmed23n', '').replace('.xml.gz', '')) for i in filename_list]`

Answer (score 1):

What @Barmar said its correct. But if you really want to use regex, you can use the `re.search()` function to do this.

`re.search()` takes two arguments: The regex pattenr that you want and the string you want to apply the regex to.

So in this case:

```
filename_cut_list = [re.search(r'^pubmed23n([0-9]*)\.xml\.gz$', x).group(1) for x in filename_list]
```

Hope this helps.

## EDIT

This will fail if the pattern is not found in the filename. Since it will throw a Exception.

Comment: Although I'm gonna take @Barmar 's answer, I'm curious what's in `group(1)` of `re.search` because I never thought re.search can be used for string replacement. and lucky if I go with your solution I shouldn't get an error because I keep only items matching the `^pubmed23n[0-9]*\.xml\.gz$` in the `filename_list`

Comment: As documentation says re.search, Scans through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. So we introduce the pattern that we want -> ...([0-9]*).. And returns a groups of matches. In this case we will only have one and so we take it with group(1) (the first match).

Comment: O I didn't notice the `()` making a group. Thanks for explanation!